# CSS hover covers over arrow overlapping onto div

Tags: css

I have a portfolio site here:

http://mrliger.com/index2.php

I have an issue whenever I hover of the menu li elements on the left side. The hover state changes the background color of the li to a darker grey but at the same time covers the arrow just to the right of the menu item. I'd like the arrow to always be visible. I've tried using z-index but no joy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property only works on positioned elements (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`). This simple CSS should work for you:

```
.topnavi {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

OR:

```
.arrow-up {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Note: For future questions, it's better if you add the code here instead provide a link.

Comment: works perfect, thanks! had no idea z index only worked on position elements